# Array search not working as expected

Tags: php

I am trying to replace the value **Event Id** in the `$fields` array with the value that is mapped to (**idEvent**) in the `$aliases` array, but PHP's `array_search` function is returning the wrong position. Note: I am converting the values to all lower case so it should return a match, and it seems like `array_search` is returning a index, but it should be returning index `2` instead of index `1` since it is the third value in the `$fields` array.

Unfortunately, if you run the code (e.g. copy and paste it here: http://writecodeonline.com/php/), it returns the wrong value. Could someone please tell me if I am doing something wrong?

```
$fields = array('Host', 'OS', 'Event Id');
$aliases = array('idEvent' => 'Event ID');

 foreach ($aliases as $actual => $alias){

    $alias = strtolower($alias);

    echo "searching fields(" . implode(',', array_map('strtolower', $fields)) . ") for $alias<br/>";
    if ($position = array_search($alias, array_map('strtolower', $fields)) !== FALSE) {

        echo "$alias was found at \$fields[$position]";
        $fields[$position] = $actual;

    }
}
```

Edit: I added some echo statements so you can what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the order of operations of the `if` statement that's the problem. The assignment operator has [lower precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than the comparison operator, and the assignment is evaluated from the right first.  So add some parenthesis:

```
if (($position = array_search($alias, array_map('strtolower', $fields))) !== FALSE) {
```

I find this easier to read:

```
if (in_array($alias, array_map('strtolower', $fields))) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array_search($alias, array_map('strtolower', $fields)) !== FALSE
```

This is true right? Then it translates to `$position = 1` and therefor you see it he found the key one but actually returns the value of the equal...

Use parenthesis or store the value of the search beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

`$position` is getting assigned value of 1 because its the result of comparing your `array_search to !== FALSE`

use the test at the left side to fix the issue.

```
if (false !== ($position = array_search($alias, array_map('strtolower', $fields)))) {

        echo "$alias was found at {$fields[$position]}";
        $fields[$position] = $actual;

    }
```